# Handling dangling nodes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have a datafile of line features. The creation of a topology revealed that there are too many dangling nodes to be corrected manually.

I was thinking of snapping to the closest line feature in an automated process, however, I do not have the Data Reviewer license of ArcGIS with which this would actually be possible (with the tool 'Snap').

How do I correct those dangling nodes in an automated process probably by a work around without the Data Reviewer license?

Comment: Did you try increasing the cluster tolerance used when you create the topology?

Comment: The tool Snap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 doesn't need a reviewer license, only standard or advanced desktop license. Be careful with bulk snapping operations, you should keep a backup and check the results *thoroughly* to ensure the snap hasn't broken something else.